# Increment a users login count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing application where a user can log in etc. This does not use devise works fine. I wanted to create a feature that counts the users login attempts and as such increments this by one each time they log in. I am aware of active record and increment as i have put below.

```
 def increment_login_count!
 update_attribute(:login_count, login_count + 1)
 end
```

Could anyone offer any other advice as to how to do this logic. I wanted to start with a controller spec and work from this but i am a little unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def increment_login_count
   increment! :login_count
end
```

And you can call this method whenever a new session is created for the user

You can refer to [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) for more information